# lpr says "unknown printer" but lpstat shows printer correctly

Tags: debian, printing, printer, debian-jessie, lpr

I'm configuring a USB printer in Debian 8.9 and am running into issues. I have configured the printer using the CUPS web interface and named it "elise". I have run lpstat which shows :

```
$ lpstat -p -d
printer elise is idle.  enabled since Thu 23 Nov 2017 14:19:29 CET
```

Then I tried printing a test page using lpr :

```
$ echo 'test' | lpr -P elise
lpr: elise: unknown printer
```

I ran these two commands one right after the other and without touching the USB connection, so I am obviously missing something here.

I have checked that lpr was not aliased to anything :

```
$ type lpr
lpr is /usr/bin/lpr
```

Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
sudo apt remove lpr
sudo apt install cups-bsd
```

helped with the same issue on a debian-based system.

I've found the solution [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/lpr-cannot-see-printer-4175505301/), michaelk wrote:

> I suspect that lpr is the actual BSD printing system vs cups-lpr. The cups-bsd package includes the lpr,lprm compatibility layer which
> may not be installed.